# how to modify a String from a Textfield before validated using validator?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-form-builder

I am using [form field validator](https://pub.dev/packages/form_field_validator), I think it will be the same if using normal `TextField`, and I have form field like this

```
  TextFormField(  
    onChanged: (val) => selectedEmail = val,  
    validator: EmailValidator(errorText: "Email is not valid"),  
  )
```

unfortunately, my user sometimes unintentionally will put an empty string at the end of email string like this :

`"john@gmail.com     "`

as you can see, I have email validator here, but the email validator will consider the string with empty space like that as an invalid email.

I want to remove or trim the email string first before it is validated by the `EmailValidator`, how to do that?

Comment: Did you try string.trim()?

Answer (score 1):

```
  TextFormField(  
    onChanged: (val) => selectedEmail = val,  
    validator: EmailValidator(errorText: "Email is not valid"),  
        inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'\s'))]

  )
```

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'\s'))` it's deny white space in the `TextFormField`

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpful.

```
TextFormField(  
    onChanged: (val) => selectedEmail.trim() = val.trim(),  
    validator: EmailValidator(errorText: "Email is not valid"),  
  )
```